# Align Two Data Frame To Make It Identical Based On Specific Row Values

Tags: r, dataframe

The data set I am using has two sub data tables that I want to align based on specific values in a row that start from specific column.

As shown below, the two tables are identical except values in third row of twelfth column.

Using `R` want to remove all the columns from either of the tables by comparing whether the values `100`, `102`, `103` and `104` in third row from table one is in table two and then checking if whether values `101`, `102` and `100` in third row from table two is in table one.

In short, want to keep columns starting `X1` that are in both tables based on values in third row of `X1` column. I also want to sort it such that `X1` in table one is same `X1` in table two based on third row value.

The steps tried so far involve breaking down data into sub-data and then removing upper columns such that the row I am interested becomes the column header. This process is too time consuming when data is big.

Anyone has a better elegant solution please?

I wanted to paste structure using `dput()` for anyone to load example faster, but StackOverflow said I have too much code and less text. Hence sharing only tables as example.

**Input Data Table One**

```
   A X0 X0.1 X0.2 X0.3 X0.4 X0.5 X0.6 X0.7 X0.8 X0.9   X1   X2   X3   X4
1  B  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    2    3    4
2  C  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0                    
3  D  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  100  102  103  104
4  E  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   mV   mV   mV   mV
5  F  G    F    G    F    G    F    G    F    G    F    1    2    3    4
6  1  1    1 25 1    0    1    1                     10.1 10.1 10.1 10.1
7  2  1    1 25 2    0    1    1                     10.1 10.1 10.1 10.1
8  3  1    1 25 3    0    1    1                     10.1 10.1 10.1 10.1
9  4  1    1 25 4    0    1    1                     10.1 10.1 10.1 10.1
10 5  1    1 25 5    0    1    1                     10.1 10.1 10.1 10.1
11 6  1    1 25 6    0    1    1                     10.1 10.1 10.1 10.1
```

**Input Data Table Two**

```
   A X0 X0.1 X0.2 X0.3 X0.4 X0.5 X0.6 X0.7 X0.8 X0.9   X1   X2   X3
1  B  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    2    3
2  C  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0               
3  D  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  101  102  100
4  E  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   mV   mV   mV
5  F  G    F    G    F    G    F    G    F    G    F    5    2    1
6  1  1    1 25 1    0    1    1                     10.1 10.1 10.1
7  2  1    1 25 2    0    1    1                     10.1 10.1 10.1
8  3  1    1 25 3    0    1    1                     10.1 10.1 10.1
9  4  1    1 25 4    0    1    1                     10.1 10.1 10.1
10 5  1    1 25 5    0    1    1                     10.1 10.1 10.1
11 6  1    1 25 6    0    1    1                     10.1 10.1 10.1
```

---

**Expected Output Data Table One**

```
   A X0 X0.1 X0.2 X0.3 X0.4 X0.5 X0.6 X0.7 X0.8 X0.9   X1   X2
1  B  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    2
2  C  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0                    
3  D  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  100  102
4  E  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   mV   mV
5  F  G    F    G    F    G    F    G    F    G    F    1    2
6  1  1    1 25 1    0    1    1                     10.1 10.1
7  2  1    1 25 2    0    1    1                     10.1 10.1
8  3  1    1 25 3    0    1    1                     10.1 10.1
9  4  1    1 25 4    0    1    1                     10.1 10.1
10 5  1    1 25 5    0    1    1                     10.1 10.1
11 6  1    1 25 6    0    1    1                     10.1 10.1
```

**Expected Output Data Table Two**

```
   A X0 X0.1 X0.2 X0.3 X0.4 X0.5 X0.6 X0.7 X0.8 X0.9   X1   X2
1  B  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    2
2  C  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0               
3  D  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  100  102
4  E  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   mV   mV
5  F  G    F    G    F    G    F    G    F    G    F    1    2
6  1  1    1 25 1    0    1    1                     10.1 10.1
7  2  1    1 25 2    0    1    1                     10.1 10.1
8  3  1    1 25 3    0    1    1                     10.1 10.1
9  4  1    1 25 4    0    1    1                     10.1 10.1
10 5  1    1 25 5    0    1    1                     10.1 10.1
11 6  1    1 25 6    0    1    1                     10.1 10.1
```

Comment: Can you share your expected output ?

Comment: @RonakShah - Added expected output, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could try to use `intersect` to find out values which are common between two dataframes at specific places and then subset the dataframe based on the values which are present.

```
vals <- intersect(df1[3, 12:ncol(df1)], df2[3, 12:ncol(df2)])

cbind(df1[1:11], df1[12:ncol(df1)][df1[3, 12:ncol(df1)] %in% vals])

#   A X0 X0.1 X0.2 X0.3 X0.4 X0.5 X0.6 X0.7 X0.8 X0.9   X1   X2
#1  B  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    2
#2  C  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 <NA> <NA>
#3  D  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  100  102
#4  E  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   mV   mV
#5  F  G    F    G    F    G    F    G    F    G    F    1    2
#6  1  1    1 25_1    0    1    1 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> 10.1 10.1
#7  2  1    1 25_2    0    1    1 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> 10.1 10.1
#8  3  1    1 25_3    0    1    1 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> 10.1 10.1
#9  4  1    1 25_4    0    1    1 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> 10.1 10.1
#10 5  1    1 25_5    0    1    1 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> 10.1 10.1
#11 6  1    1 25_6    0    1    1 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> 10.1 10.1
```

and similar for `df2`

```
cbind(df2[1:11], df2[12:ncol(df2)][df2[3, 12:ncol(df2)] %in% vals])
```

Column names can be renamed if needed.

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c("B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6"), X0 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "G", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1"), X0.1 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "F", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1"), X0.2 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "G", "25_1", "25_2", 
"25_3", "25_4", "25_5", "25_6"), X0.3 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", 
"F", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), X0.4 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", 
"G", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), X0.5 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", 
"F", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), X0.6 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", 
"G", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X0.7 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "F", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X0.8 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "G", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X0.9 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "F", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), X1 = c("1", NA, "100", "mV", "1", "10.1", "10.1", 
"10.1", "10.1", "10.1", "10.1"), X2 = c("2", NA, "102", "mV", 
"2", "10.1", "10.1", "10.1", "10.1", "10.1", "10.1"), X3 = c("3", 
NA, "103", "mV", "3", "10.1", "10.1", "10.1", "10.1", "10.1", 
"10.1"), X4 = c("4", NA, "104", "mV", "4", "10.1", "10.1", "10.1", 
"10.1", "10.1", "10.1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"))

df2 <- structure(list(A = c("B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6"), X0 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "G", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1"), X0.1 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "F", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1"), X0.2 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "G", "25_1", "25_2", 
"25_3", "25_4", "25_5", "25_6"), X0.3 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", 
"F", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), X0.4 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", 
"G", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), X0.5 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", 
"F", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), X0.6 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", 
"G", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X0.7 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "F", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X0.8 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "G", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X0.9 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "F", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), X1 = c("1", NA, "101", "mV", "5", "10.1", "10.1", 
"10.1", "10.1", "10.1", "10.1"), X2 = c("2", NA, "102", "mV", 
"2", "10.1", "10.1", "10.1", "10.1", "10.1", "10.1"), X3 = c("3", 
NA, "100", "mV", "1", "10.1", "10.1", "10.1", "10.1", "10.1", 
"10.1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"))
```

Comment: .@RonakShah - Thanks. Why did in output table, column `4` row `6` to `11` replaced `space` with  `_`?

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil I added them in my sample input data itself since it was difficult for me to read the data with a space. Also added NA instead of space. Nothing changes there, your data would remain as it is.

Comment: .@RonakShah - I am getting `Error in intersect_data_frame(x, y) : 
  not compatible: different number of columns : 4 x 3` error on the same data above. Also exact issue on the big data I am applying your code logic.

Comment: .@RonakShah - Does it matter whether I write it like `intersect(df1[3, 12:ncol(df1)], df2[3, 12:ncol(df2)])` OR `intersect(df2[3, 12:ncol(df2)], df1[3, 12:ncol(df1)])`? This can be crucial when first data frame has more columns to compare against than second, and vice versa. Any column (irrespective of which table it's coming from) that doesn't match (as per the subset criteria in OP) finds a match, is expected to be remove from both.

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil no, it does not matter what comes first for `intersect`. Check `intersect(1:10, 1:2)` and `intersect(1:2, 1:10)`. So no matter how you use, it should give you the same result.

Comment: .@RonakShah - I am getting `Error in intersect_data_frame(x, y) : not compatible: different number of columns : 4 x 3` error on the same data above. Also exact issue on the big data I am applying your code logic.

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil I don't get the error using the `dput` which I have shared in my answer. `intersect(df1[3, 12:ncol(df1)], df2[3, 12:ncol(df2)])` gives `100 102` and `intersect(df2[3, 12:ncol(df2)], df1[3, 12:ncol(df1)])` gives `102 100`.

Comment: .@RonakShah - Can you load the structure you added in your answer please? Then running your solution works for you?

Comment: .@RonakShah - Looks like `intersect()` is part of multiple package including `dplyr()` and in my code I was using `dplyr()` for other use case. Can you please confirm you were using `intersect()` after loading `generics()` library? That's why it works for you and not for me. Worked after I cleaned workspace and loaded `generics()` and ran your solution.

Comment: I see. In that case, you need to specify `base::intersect` explicitly.